# How grouping json objects in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: json, wso2, grouping, esb, wso2-esb

I have this json response :

```
{
  "field": [
    {
      "id": 26,
      "name": "tom",
      "email": "aaa@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "lisa",
      "email": "ss@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "hi",
      "email": "ss@hotmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to group it by Id and convert it like this :

```
{
  26: [{
  name: " tom",
  email: "aaa@hotmail.com",

}],
  11: [{
 name: "lisa"
  email: "ss@hotmail.com"};
{
 name: "hi"
  email: "ss@hotmail.com"}

}]
}
```

I should use Wso2esb to do that, I try T use script mediator and it is return error, please can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option that you can use for this is the data mapper mediator. You can perform a JSON-JSON mapping to achieve your requirement. To configure the data mapper you need to use the integration studio [1]. For the data mapper, you need to provide the sample input data, sample output data file. This can then be graphically mapped in the integration studio. Please refer to the documentation [2] to further clarify this.

[1]-https://wso2.com/integration/integration-studio/
[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Data+Mapper+Mediator

Comment: Thank you very much Shanaka Premarathna, I use this option but I faced issue, the output print the last object on the array , how to let it print all the objects by ID ?

Comment: can you share the Synapse configurations used in your environment

Comment: {"$schema":"http:\/\/wso2.org\/json-schema\/wso2-data-mapper-v5.0.0\/schema#","inputType":"JSON","id":"","title":"sending","type":"object","properties":{"field":{"id":"","type":"array","items":[{"id":"\/0","type":"object","properties":{"email":{"id":"null\/0","type":"string"},"id":{"id":"null\/0","type":"number"},"name":{"id":"null\/0","type":"string"}}}]}}}

Comment: {"$schema":"http:\/\/wso2.org\/json-schema\/wso2-data-mapper-v5.0.0\/schema#","outputType":"JSON","id":"","title":"sending","type":"object","properties":{"field":{"id":"","type":"array","items":[{"id":"\/0","type":"object","properties":{"id":{"id":"","type":"array","items":[{"id":"\/0","type":"object","value":{"type":"number"},"properties":{"email":{"id":"null\/0","type":"string"},"name":{"id":"null\/0","type":"string"}}}]}}}]}}}

Comment: this is the output , it prints the last object :{
    "field": [
        {
            "id": [
                {
                    "_ELEMVAL": 11,
                    "name": "hi",
                    "email": "ss@hotmail.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Analyzing the JSON output that you expect in the issue raised, I could observe that this is not a valid JSON. Can you modify the JSON file for a valid JSON========{
  26: [{
  name: " tom",
  email: "aaa@hotmail.com",

}],
  11: [{
 name: "lisa"
  email: "ss@hotmail.com"};
{
 name: "hi"
  email: "ss@hotmail.com"}

}]
}

Comment: I modify the json file as you said but still print the last object , I think it's need for loop in .dmc file , I try to add for loop and categorize objects by id but my code does not work , any idea for editing .dmc?  Thank you

Comment: This is .dmc file : for(i_field_1d3861bd_c355_45b8_9b7e_5eb52941ba97 in inputroot.field){
outputroot.field[0] =  {};
outputroot.field[0].id =  [];
outputroot.field[0].id[0] =  {};
outputroot.field[0].id[0]._ELEMVAL = inputroot.field[i_field_1d3861bd_c355_45b8_9b7e_5eb52941ba97].id;
outputroot.field[0].id[0].name = inputroot.field[i_field_1d3861bd_c355_45b8_9b7e_5eb52941ba97].name;
outputroot.field[0].id[0].email = inputroot.field[i_field_1d3861bd_c355_45b8_9b7e_5eb52941ba97].email;

count_i_field_1d3861bd_c355_45b8_9b7e_5eb52941ba97++;
}
return outputroot;
};

Comment: {
  "field": [
{
  26: [{
  name: " tom",
  email: "aaa@hotmail.com",

}],
  11: [{
 name: "lisa"
  email: "ss@hotmail.com"};
{
 name: "hi"
 email: "ss@hotmail.com"}

}]]}
}                  26 and 11 are the id which is not fixed

Comment: This is still not a valid JSON. Can you use an online tool such as to validate this.https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and create a valid JSON

Comment: { "field": [ 
26, [{ "name": " tom", 
email: "aaa@hotmail.com", }], 
11, [{ "name": "lisa",
"email": "ss@hotmail.com"}, 
{ "name": "hi" ,"email": "ss@hotmail.com"} ]] }                                                                       Grouping the objects by id

Comment: It seems that at the moment we do not have the facility to automatically generate the input schema when there are arrays within arrays. You will need to manually edit the .dmc file create the mapping

Comment: thank you very much Shanaka , yes I edited .dmc file and it's work , my code is : results = result.field;
groups = {};
for (var i in results) {
  var groupName = results[i].id;
  if (!groups[results[i].id]) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
  }
 groups[groupName].push({"name" :results[i].name,"email":results[i].email})
}
console.log(groups);